# Code excel VBA Userform to enter data into multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Please be patient with me as I try to explain this. I'm trying to develop a data entry form to take into the field with our crew that will automatically download into our desired excel sheet. We write down multiple species per point per vegetation plot. I have created a drop down species list to reduce error for each selection but have no idea how to get it to download the information across multiple rows. I can only make it work for one row (I know a forloop needs to be made but don't understand the language well enough) or how to include the location of the sample without having the user input that information. I have included what the form and excel format looks like.

Userform:
[image: Form]

Worksheet:
[image: Worksheet]

Here is the code I currently have, that works for the first row of information. I would like the meter distance to automatically be inputted and I would like project ID, plot ID, and date to also be rewritten every time a new row of information is downloaded. Is this even possible? Am I overdoing it?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

erow = Sheets("sheet1").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("a" & erow + 1) = cboProjectID.Value
    Range("b" & erow + 1) = TextBox2.Value
    Range("c" & erow + 1) = TextBox3.Value
    Range("d" & erow + 1) = cboFieldCrew.Value
    Range("e" & erow + 1) = cboAzimuth.Value
    Range("g" & erow + 1) = cboSPP1.Value
    Range("h" & erow + 1) = cboSPP2.Value
    Range("i" & erow + 1) = cboSPP3.Value
    Range("j" & erow + 1) = cboSPP4.Value
    Range("k" & erow + 1) = cboSPP5.Value
    Range("l" & erow + 1) = cboSPP6.Value
    Range("m" & erow + 1) = cboSPP7.Value
    Range("n" & erow + 1) = cboSPP8.Value

    cboProjectID.Value = ""
    TextBox2.Value = ""
    TextBox3.Value = ""
    cboFieldCrew.Value = ""
    cboAzimuth.Value = ""
    cboSPP1.Value = ""
    cboSPP2.Value = ""
    cboSPP3.Value = ""
    cboSPP4.Value = ""
    cboSPP5.Value = ""
    cboSPP6.Value = ""
    cboSPP7.Value = ""
    cboSPP8.Value  = ""


End Sub
```

Comment: okay I see what you mean for the naming convention-but it can't just be added to the bottom as another *Range("n" & erow + 1) = cboSPP8.Value* because the cell is already attached to the original one.

Comment: Should be clearer in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your first row of comboboxes follow a naming convention of `cboSPP1` to `cboSPP8`
I would maybe change that to something like `cboSPP1_1` to `cboSPP1_8` for the first row, then `cboSPP2_1 to cboSPP2_8` for the second row, etc. Then you can use a loop and something like

`Me.Controls("cboSSP" & lineNum & "_" & SPPNum).Value`

to access the value of the relevant drop-down.

Same sort of thing for your "meter" labels.

Untested:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    
    Dim rw As Range, lineNum As Long, SPPNum As Long, arrInfo, arrSPP, con As Control
    
    'the next unused row (in ColA)
    Set rw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
    
    'information to be repeated on each line...
    arrInfo = Array(cboProjectID.Value, TextBox2.Value, TextBox3.Value, _
                    cboFieldCrew.Value, cboAzimuth.Value)
    
    For lineNum = 1 To 9 'however many lines of info you have
        rw.Columns("A").Resize(1, UBound(arrInfo) + 1).Value = arrInfo      'assign repeated info from array
        rw.Columns("F").Value = Me.Controls("lblMeters" & lineNum).Caption  'read the "meters" label
        For SPPNum = 1 To 8 'loop the species combos for this row
            rw.Columns("G").Offset(0, SPPNum - 1) = _
                Me.Controls("cboSSP" & lineNum & "_" & SPPNum).Value
        Next SPPNum
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1) 'next worksheet row for output
    Next lineNum
    
    'clear the form
    cboProjectID.Value = ""
    TextBox2.Value = ""
    TextBox3.Value = ""
    cboFieldCrew.Value = ""
    cboAzimuth.Value = ""
    
    'reset all SPP combos
    For Each con In Me.Controls
        If con.Name Like "cboSPP*" Then con.Value = ""
    Next con
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This has been very helpful; I have been stuck on this line of code tho:  rw.Columns("G").Offset(0, SPPNum - 1) = _
                Me.Controls("cboSPP" & lineNum & "_" & SPPNum).Value         (it says it could not find the specified object) I am assuming it has to do with SPPNum part? it seems to be uploading well tho! what does the offset do?

Comment: Your first spp value goes into column G. SPPNum at that point is one, so there's no column Offset, but as the value of SPPNum goes up the column offset increases and the next column in the row gets populated.   If you're getting an error it's possible you mis-named one of the comboboxes and there's no existing control named  `"cboSSP" & lineNum & "_" & SPPNum`